# Factory interface in swift

Tags: swift

what are the ways we can create factory method and shared instance in swift.

I have 2 classes Apple and Orange. I would like to create single interface which will return share instance of either class, lets say "Fruit". If application is running on iphone it will return "Apple" instance and in other case "Orange"

What are the ways in swift I can create single interface "Fruit"?

```
class Apple:Fruit {
    static let instance = Apple()

}

class Orange:Fruit {
    static let instance = Orange()

}
```

Now I would like to create Fruit class which will return shared instance based on device something like this,

```
class Fruit: NSObject {
    // Check device
    // if iphone
    // return Apple instance
    // else
    // return Orange instance
}
```

Comment: I'll leave the Swift ways to the better expects here, but this *feels* wrong to me. In basic OOP terms, an Apple or Orange would inherit from a Fruit, not the other way around. I'm guessing you'd be better off rethinking or refactoring that part.

Comment: you can use the `UIDevice` class to get the type of device. For example `UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone"`